# How to change the scale of an axis with HighChart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using HighChart to display the memory usage of some containers. The problem is that sometimes the scale is in K sometimes in M and sometimes with nothing (like the picture bellow):
[image]

And this is how I create my HighChart:

```
var cursor = Template.currentData();
    liveChart = Highcharts.chart(cursor.chart_id, {
        title: {
            text: 'Memory usage of the controlcontainers_mongo_1'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'usage'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>';
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'memory usage',
            data: []
        }]
    });
```

[EDIT] Maybe it could be helpful to see the entire graph so there is it:
[image]

This is my formatter if someone need it:

```
formatter: function() {
                 var usage = this.value;
                 if((usage >= 1000000)&&(usage < 1000000000)){
                   return (usage/1000000).toFixed(2) + "MB";
                 }else if (usage >= 1000000000) {
                   return (usage/1000000000).toFixed(2) + "GB";
                 }else{
                   return usage + "KB";
                 }
               }
```

Comment: Do you want to round K values to nearest decimal point?

Comment: Yes it could do the work, but I think like in the picture that I added it should display M because 56600k would be better to be displayed in M and then if the usage is 56600M it should be in G. You see the logic ?

Comment: I have mentioned the way to access the value of label in Y axis, you can play with that and display the way you want

Comment: @AnandG ok thank you for your help so now I'll just put some ìf`in the function :) But I'm not sure about how to put the k,m,g next to the value, is it made automatically ?

Comment: You can concatenate it to the value.

Comment: Yes I'll but  I need to wait Xmin before. And yep I founded how to make it in your website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can round up the values in y-axis formatting function

```html
    var cursor = Template.currentData();
    liveChart = Highcharts.chart(cursor.chart_id, {
        title: {
            text: 'Memory usage of the controlcontainers_mongo_1'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'usage'
            },
            labels: {
                 formatter: function() {
                     //This will round the value, but you can do anything to this value now
                     return this.value.toFixed(2);
                 }
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>';
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'memory usage',
            data: []
        }]
    });
```

Read more [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes)